# How to put combobox Items in a list?

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, combobox

I added Items to a combobox using:

```
SqlDataReader sqlReader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();
while (sqlReader.Read())
{
    string name = sqlReader.GetString(0);
    combobox1.Items.Add(name);
}
sqlReader.Close();
conn.Close();
```

Now I want to put these value in a string list. Is that possible and how can I do that?

Comment: Declare and initialize a list of strings `List<string>` and add the _name_ to this list after or before adding it to the combobox items.

Comment: I want to access these items from a different scope (inside an event handler)

Comment: That is possible you just have to instantiate the List above the current method you are in

Comment: this will make it accessible throughout the rest of the class (example in my answer)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Simply you can do something like

```
string[] items = new string[combobox1.Items.Count];  

 for(int i = 0; i < combobox1.Items.Count; i++)
   {
       items[i] = combobox1.Items[i].ToString();
   }
```

Or if want to Create a string list directly from reader object than

```
var itemList=new List<string>();
SqlDataReader sqlReader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (sqlReader.Read())
                {

                    string name = sqlReader.GetString(0);
                    combobox1.Items.Add(name);
                    itemList.Add(name);
                }
                sqlReader.Close();
                conn.Close();
            }
```

Use of LINQ will make you job very easier

```
var arr = combobox1.Items.Cast<Object>()
      .Select(item => item.ToString()).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
private List<string> ComboBoxList = new List<string>();
```

Create this outside of the method you are currently in. This List will allow you to use it in any method within the class.

```
private List<string> ComboBoxList;
```

or Try this instead of the top piece of code. They both work.

```
SqlDataReader sqlReader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (sqlReader.Read())
            {

                string name = sqlReader.GetString(0);
                combobox1.Items.Add(name);
                comboBoxList.Add(name);
            }
            sqlReader.Close();
            conn.Close();
        }
```

Create a new list and add each name to the list.

Comment: `comboBoxList.Items.Add(name);` this is not the correct way to add item in string

Comment: Sorry thats my bad. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there's a more elegant method, but this works

```
List<string> values = this.ComKeyType.Items
                      .Cast<object>()
                      .Select(x => x.ToString().Split('=')[1].Replace(" }", "").Trim())
                      .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want this:

```
List<String>  cbList = new List<String>();

var lstItems= ComboBox1.Items.Cast<Object>()
          .Select(item => item.ToString()).ToList();

cbList.Add(lstItems);
```

Comment: is there a way to put it in a string list ?

Answer (score 0):

You would really need to separate concerns in your code to make it maintainable.

If you want to bind a list to combobox, you can do it in XAML:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}" SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentItem}" />
```

You'd better make an ObservableCollection property in your view model:

```
public ObservableCollection<string> MyList {get; private set;}
```

and initialize it in your view model's constructor:

```
MyList = new ObservableCollection<string>(GetNames());
```

`GetNames()` here is the method where your SQL code is incapsulated:

```
private List<string> GetNames() {
    var myList = new List<string>();
    SqlDataReader sqlReader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (sqlReader.Read())
        {
            string name = sqlReader.GetString(0);
            myList.Add(name);
        }
    sqlReader.Close();
    conn.Close();

    return myList;
}
```